# Elements to switch each other on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make `#switch` visible after the `.content` element is hovered and to make `#caption` disappear.

Like the element IDs suggest, the `#switch` element should replace the caption on hover. I used Javascript to work that out, but `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` functions did not work with `.content` and `#caption` and `#switch` are abruptly shifting on hover.

```js
document.getElementById('caption').onmouseover = function() {
  displaySwitch()
};
document.getElementById('switch').onmouseout = function() {
  hideSwitch()
};

function displaySwitch() {
  document.getElementById('caption').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('switch').style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hideSwitch() {
  document.getElementById('switch').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('caption').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#caption {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#switch {
  /* The element is hidden in advance. */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a id="caption">Lorem Ipsum</a>

  <div id="switch">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ornare libero et vestibulum pellentesque. In accumsan et est dapibus viverra.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What's your question? It looks like you've achieved the intended behaviour you've described.

Comment: My question is how to make it so that the Lores Ipsum text appears when the box is hovered (and not the caption). Also, the behaviour it has is not smooth now either. The texts are switching abruptly and randomly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement '*to make #switch visible after the .content element is hovered and to make #caption disappear*', added new id `box` to `content` element. And bind `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events to `box` element.

Please verify the output, is it as per your requirement or I did something different?

```js
document.getElementById('box').onmouseover = function() {
  displaySwitch()
};

document.getElementById('box').onmouseout = function() {
  hideSwitch()
};

function displaySwitch() {
  document.getElementById('caption').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('switch').style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hideSwitch() {
  document.getElementById('switch').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('caption').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#caption {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#switch {
  /* The element is hidden in advance. */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="box">
  <a id="caption">Lorem Ipsum</a>

  <div id="switch">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ornare libero et vestibulum pellentesque. In accumsan et est dapibus viverra.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```